# Cyclomatic complexity in Legacy VB6.0 application

Tags: vb6, code-analysis, fxcop, cyclomatic-complexity

Suggest any tool that  **should support to VB6.0**

I am looking for  following metrics

1. Code Analysis
2. Code Maintainability Index
3. Cyclomatic complexity

Comment: Consider that VB6 is long since end-of-lifed, you should be pretty surprised if the answer was yes.   You might do better to ask if there are any code analysis tools for VB6, regardless of source.

Comment: Sure - am adding it in to description section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the tool [VBDepend](http://www.vbdepend.com/)? It indeed supports Cyclomatic Complexity, more code metrics, and static analysis, for VB6 code.

*Disclaimer: I collaborate with one of the developer of the tool.*

Answer (score 1):

I use [Aivosto Project Analyzer](http://www.aivosto.com/) and find it satisfactory. It also works for VB.Net, for whenever you get round to porting.

Comment: Yes  i found this tool very useful.